# How do I make a callback for startActivityForResult() if I don't can't change the Activity?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm making a Cordova plugin and I'm using `startActivityForResult()` to make Bluetooth discoverable. I want to run a method in my plugin when Intent finishes. I can't modify the Activity directly, how else can I make a callback?

Here's what I have:

```
    if(bt.getScanMode()!=BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE){
        if(bt.isEnabled())
            bt.disable();

        Intent intent=new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        intent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION,0);
        cordova.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,Leo.BT_DISCOVERABLE_INTENT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your plugin class, you have to implement the onActivityResult function to deal with the intent's result and then call either callbackContext.success in case of success or callbackContext.error in case of failute :

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        this.callbackContext.success(intent.getStringExtra("result"));
    } else {
        String message = intent == null ? "null intent!" : intent.getStringExtra("result");
        this.callbackContext.error(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought onActivityResult  had to go in the Activity class?

Comment: Your app's activity class extends CordovaActivity, CordovaActivity contains a onActivityResult function that chains to onActivityResult function in plugin classes that extend CordovaPlugin class.

Answer (score 0):

In the activity:

```
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
finish();
```